# In "El burlador de Sevilla", why is "matara" and not "matad" in "Haced prender y matara ese hombre y esta mujer"?

Tags: conjugación

> Haced prender y matara ese hombre y esta mujer

I don't understand *matara*. Is this future or imp subj. and why doesn't it agree with 2nd plural? I think it means "Capture and kill this man and woman".

Context:

> don pedro. —¿Voces en tu cuarto gran señor? ¿Quién causa este rumor?
>
> rey. —Haced prender y **matara** ese hombre y esta mujer.
>
> don pedro. —¿Quiénes son?
>
> rey. — No necesito conocerlos. Al verlos aquí, he  visto bastante."

Comment: Probably just a typo. The sentence should be "haced prender y matar a ese hombre y esta mujer". Thus the imperatives are "haced prender" and "haced matar". The meaning is "send someone to capture and kill that man and this woman".

Comment: All the references I found mention _Haced prender y matar / ese hombre y esta mujer_. Thus, this _a_ is just a typo.

Comment: I find more interesting the following question: why does don Pedro use "tu" and "gran señor" in the same sentence? Shouldn't it be "su cuarto" or even "vuestro cuarto"?

Comment: It has very strange uses like vos used like vosotros, I guess because it is so old, like when don juan says "¿Vos os habéis de vengar, buen viejo?" I found the explanation in one of my grammar books: Antiguamente, las formas plurale de la 1a y 2a personas del plural eran las
formas nos y vos, pero tónicas. Hoy quedan residuos del uso de nos y vos, en función
de sujeto; es lo que denominamo el plural mayestatico: «Nos, Católico
Apostólico Romano Pontffice, declaramos». « Vos ordenais, Majestad ... ».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a typo: there should be a space before the last "a" in "matara". It should be:

> Rey. —Haced prender y **matar a** ese hombre y esta mujer.

**EDIT**
I have checked two editions of the play (the one I have at home and the one available for free at the "*Biblioteca Virtual Miguel de Cervantes*" [**(link)**](http://descargas.cervantesvirtual.com/servlet/SirveObras/01260963765699435228813/019467.pdf) and couldn't find the text you quote. The closest I find is at the very beginning of the play (act I:  verses 22 - 36):

> REY: ¿Qué es?
>   JUAN: Qué ha de ser?
>   Un hombre y una mujer.
>   REY: Esto en prudencia consiste.
>   ¡Ah de mi guarda! Prendé 
>   a este hombre.
>   ISABELA: ¡Ay, perdido honor!
>
> Sale don PEDRO Tenorio, embajador de España, y GUARDA
>
> PEDRO: ¡En tu cuarto, gran señor
>   voces! ¿Quién la causa fue?
>   REY: Don Pedro Tenorio, a vos
>   esta prisión os encargo.
>   Si ando corto, andad vos largo.
>   Mirad quién son estos dos.
>   Y con secreto ha de ser,
>   que algún mal suceso creo;
>   porque si yo aquí los veo,
>   no me queda más que ver.
>
> Vase el REY
>
> PEDRO: Prendedle.
>   JUAN: ¿Quién ha de osar?
>   Bien puedo perder la vida;
>   mas ha de ir tan bien vendida
>   que a alguno le ha de pesar.
>   PEDRO: Matadle."

which makes me suspect that you are using an adapted version, and reinforces the possibility of a typo.

Comment: It's funny to note that in the original version is don Pedro and not the king who orders to kill them. The king only orders to capture them. Also funny: don Pedro says "tu cuarto" to the king, but the king says "a vos" to don Pedro.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: This shows that there was a time when kings were merciful and polite